# Make li background color span whole ul width CSS

Tags: html, css

This is probably an easy solution, but I am wracking my brain over this. I am trying to hover over a li that opens another ul, and once I hover over the li in the mentioned ul, the background takes up the whole width of the ul background.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul>li {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 22px;
}

ul>li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul>li li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

ul>li ul {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

ul>li li>ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover>ul,
li:focus>ul {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background: #27B3CF;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="color: white;">Reports
    <ul>
      <li>Lvl 1</li>
      <li><span class="title">Show a List</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lvl 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried using display: block; as much as I can but for some reason I cannot make the background width span the width of the drop down. I am still a beginner and could use some help to lead me in the right direction. Do you see where I can add CSS to make this adjustment? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to accomplish? What do you want  to happen?

Comment: @VandolphReyes Problem is that I hover over the list item called "Reports" and the list that follows has great display, but when I hover over the list "Details", the background as I hover only covers the length of the text, not the width of the drop down (ul).

Comment: Take a look at @Chava G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving the list items a fixed width, the background color will display across that width, versus only the size of the text and padding.

Here's your snippet, with the following addition to the `ul>li` class:

`width: 50px;`

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul>li {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 50px;
}

ul>li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul>li li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

ul>li ul {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

ul>li li>ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover>ul,
li:focus>ul {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background: #27B3CF;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li >Reports
    <ul>
      <li>Lvl 1</li>
      <li><span class="title">Show a List</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lvl 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set a fixed width, you can get rid of the float:left in the ul>li li selector setting it as float:none. It seems ok when I test in developer tools and I can't see the particular reason to have a float in that element.